# Android gridview items text value cut off

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, layout

My items appears OK in gridview when the item value is of short length, but with a long value it cuts off some of text like (Newspapers and magazines) it shows (Newspapers and mag):

```
  <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" >
    </GridView>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: gridview return item value. this text appears ok if short .but if long it comes with ... at the end and not shown all text>

Comment: maybe add padding right?!